# Mongodb/NodeJS connect to localhost SQL

Tags: sql, node.js, mongodb

I am currently trying to do some mapping of excel files using robo3t(mongodDB) and run using node. Before this, i am able to connect with my company server, but what i want now is to try do the mapping but point it to my localhost using my sql without touching anything to the company server. But seems like i might be config the wrong thing. I am really new to this, and i need help..

https://i.stack.imgur.com/78cUU.jpg - "my current code in mongo"

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZrQ5.jpg - "how my localhost in sql server looks like"

https://i.stack.imgur.com/p816e.jpg - "what i tried so far is also enabled everything in the sql server config and restart the service too!"

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZOJt.jpg - "error that i get when i run the node to initiate the mapping"

any helps/hints are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the server in your configure block (in MongoDB) as follows:

```
configure {
    "server": "flb33ctbnm\\sqlexpress"
    ..
}
```

or

```
configure {
    "server": "localhost\\sqlexpress"
    ..
}
```

Leave the other settings (username, password, etc) as they were.

Your current setting is making MongoDb look for a localhostSQLEXPRESS machine that does not exist!

Comment: Hi i tried both, but got error saying that cant connect to 1433. :( @terry lennox

Comment: Have you checked which port the SQL instance is running on? You should be able to see this one the SQL config tool, not all instances run on 1433.

Comment: Already checked, my current port is currently 0. Should i change to something else?

Comment: I'd suggest setting to 1433, also I'd try connecting to the instance using another tool such as Sqlcmd to ensure it's not something like a firewall issue.

Comment: Still can't get the connection.. previously my company using the same port, (i didn't change that in the code) should i change to other port?

Comment: Can you connect using SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: Yes i can connect and export or create any database in my local server as well. I really out of ideas why this thing wont connect to my local server :/